# 502 bad gateway in xampp v3.2.2

Tags: php, xampp, gateway, bad-gateway

My website running on xampp v3.2.2 and sometimes getting 502 while login, signup or post a data. But if we tries 2-3 time to send a request then it may works fine and sometime it works flawlessly too!! I did check with proxy, deflate, post size, memory, etc in httpd.conf and php.ini.

Comment: You have to check what the error log says. 502 errors can have many different issues.

Comment: I have checked logs it seems no errors for the same. few errors are there which occur in morning 11pm again those are irrelevant. Eg. AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway). Any one?